# Determining if drag was aborted in collectionView(_:dragSessionDidEnd:)

Tags: ios, drag-and-drop

According to Apple’s docs, “This method is called after the drag session ended, usually because the content was dropped but possibly because the drag was aborted.”

However, I can’t find any way to determine if the drag was aborted.

I’m trying to improve the visual feedback during a move operation, where an item is removed from one collection view in my app and added to another. The D&D support in iOS makes it quite easy to make the drop beautiful, but seems to offer very little feedback to improve the animations at the origin.